# Input SVG Path into DynamoDb

Tags: javascript, svg, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm having problems trying to insert a svg string into dynamodb.
The svg path is enclosed in a `<svg></svg>` tag which I think is causing the issue for the insert.

When I tried to update the table with content that has '<' and '>' it doesn't seem to correctly update the attribute with the value instead, it returns an empty string. During insertion it would seem that it negates anything between the '<' and '>'.

Comment: You can try to use `encodeURI`or `encodeURIComponent` to escape that symbols.

Comment: Basically, are you trying to save XML type data in DynamoDB?